# connected sets and ordered sets

Tags: general-topology

Let be $X$ a topological space and $\{A_n\} \subset X$ a family of connected spaces s.t $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq \varnothing$ for every  $n$.

**Claim.:** $C=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ is a connected space.

In fact if $A\subset C$ is a non empty clopen then w.l.g  $A\cap A_1\neq \varnothing$, so $A\cap A_1$ must be clopen in the subspace topology, therefore $A\cap A_1=A_1$ because $A_1$ is connected.

So we must have  $A\cap A_2\neq \varnothing$, because by hypotesis $A_1\cap A_2\neq \varnothing$..  Repeat the argument.

**My Question.:** This claim is truth if we change the naturals $\mathbb{N}$  by another ordered family of index ?

Comment: Yes. The argument does not depend on the natural numbers.

Comment: @Andre Can you explain me?

Comment: What does "$A_n\cap A_{n+1}\neq\emptyset$" mean for a general index set?

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

Prove by induction that $B_n = \cup_{i=0}^n A_i$ is connected. This uses that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered. Then as the family $B_n$ is nested now, we conclude that the union of $B_n$, which equals the union of the $A_n$, is connected.

So in this proof I would use only the well-orderedness of the index set.

But it's not necessary for the index set to be well-ordered, as we can use $\mathbb{Z}$ as well (go two directions and combine those). But then we use some successor/predecessor argument as well.

Question is, how do we formulate the condition $A_{n} \cap A_{n+1} \neq \emptyset$ for an arbitrary ordered index set? In a well-order we can use successor argument, but what about limit cases? I do think we get back to $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$-like orders in order to even formulate the condition in an analogous way, and remain in the spirit. So I do think the index set is important here. We need some discrete chain to stay in the spirit of this proposition.